# Solving an inhomogenous linear recurrence with two approaches gives back inconsistent results.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

In the textbook *Mathematics for Computer Science (2004)* by Lehman there is an example question in chapter 13.4.1 that tries to solve an inhomogenous recurrence:

$$f(1)=1\\f(n)=4f(n-1)+3^n$$

By the textbook's method where you first solve the homogenous recurrence $f(n)=4f(n-1)$, and then find a particular solution for $f(n)=4f(n-1)+3^n$, and then guess the particular solutino to be of the form $d3^n$. Finally you solve for the constants, giving the answer of $f(n)=\frac{5}{2}4^n-3^{n+1}$. However by another method gives a different answer $f(n)=2\cdot4^{n-1}-3^{n-1}$. The method is shown as follows:

$$a_n=4a_{n-1}+3^n\\
\frac{a_n}{3^n}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{a_{n-1}}{3^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{3}\right)$$
Solve $f(n)$ as a regular geometric sequence and I had the above result. What's gone wrong with my approach? Or did I miss something in the transformation?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
a_n &= 4a_{n-1} + 3^n \\
\frac{a_n}{3^n} &= \frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{a_{n-1}}{3^{n-1}} + 1 \\
\frac{a_n}{3^n} + k &= \frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{a_{n-1}}{3^{n-1}}+k\right) + 1-\frac{k}{3} \\
\end{align}
Now choose $k=3$ so that $1-k/3=0$, and let $b_n=\frac{a_n}{3^n} + 3$.  Then
$$b_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{4}{3}b_{n-1} &\text{if $n > 1$}\\
\frac{a_1}{3^1} + 3 = \frac{10}{3} &\text{if $n = 1$}\\
\end{cases}
$$
So $$b_n=\frac{10}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^{n-1},$$
which implies that
$$a_n=3^n(b_n-3)=3^n\left(\frac{10}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^{n-1}-3\right)=10\cdot4^{n-1}-3^{n+1}=\frac{5}{2}4^n-3^{n+1}$$

---

An alternative approach is to let $A(z)=\sum_{n \ge 1} a_n z^n$ be the ordinary generating function and deduce
\begin{align}
a_1 z^1 + \sum_{n \ge 2} a_n z^n &= a_1 z^1 + 4\sum_{n \ge 2}a_{n-1}z^n + \sum_{n \ge 2} 3^n z^n \\
A(z) &= z + 4zA(z) + \frac{(3z)^2}{1-3z}.
\end{align}
So
\begin{align}
A(z) &= \frac{z + \frac{(3z)^2}{1-3z}}{1-4z} \\
&= \frac{z+6z^2}{(1-4z)(1-3z)} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{5/2}{1-4z} - \frac{3}{1-3z} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{5}{2}\sum_{n \ge 0}(4z)^n - 3\sum_{n \ge 0} (3z)^n \\
&= \frac{5}{2}\sum_{n \ge 1}(4z)^n - 3\sum_{n \ge 1} (3z)^n \\
&= \sum_{n \ge 1}\left(\frac{5}{2}4^n - 3^{n+1}\right) z^n,
\end{align}
which immediately implies that
$$a_n = \frac{5}{2}4^n - 3^{n+1}.$$